# Get catalogue sort option value in Woocommerce settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to retrieve catalog/products sorting configured from Admin into my theme. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce stores the default sorting configuration in the `wp_options` table, so you can retrieve it with:

```
get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby');
```

It will return only the current configured sorting criteria.